Different sizes with ls -sh of the same dir?
From inside a directory My_dir I get the content size with ls:
$ ls -sh
total 386M
94M Kammermusik_Nocturne_chnl1.wav  94M Kammermusik_Nocturne_chnl3.wav  11M Kammermusik_Nocturne_stereo-mix.mp3
94M Kammermusik_Nocturne_chnl2.wav  94M Kammermusik_Nocturne_chnl4.wav

with a total size of 386 Megabytes. Then I read the size of the whole directory from 1 directory-level before:
$ cd ..
$ ls -sh
total 16K
4,0K Dir1  4,0K Dir2  4,0K Dir3  4,0K My_dir

The size of My_dir is shown as only 4 Kilobytes?! What am I reading false, as the total file was reported as 386M!

Your first ls shows the contents of a directory (and space used); in your second ls you show the contents of the directory itself (ie. size of metadata used to store filenames (& other metadata) within the directory, not the contents of those files).  As your different directories are viewing different things, different sizes can be expected.

Everything in Linux is a file, so is a directory, although a directory is some kind of special file. This specialf file  does not contain other files but hardlinks to other files, the so called directory entries. If the number of links exceed a certain number, the directory needs to  get bigger and will grow another 4K.
